# inotify/tool with NFS

Tags: c++, linux, nfs, inotify

I have installed inotify for monitoring file changes.We have NFS server also where we submit our jobs and the response that server  create file into my working directory. I found that inotify does not create any event and goes for hang for long period. So my question.

1) can inotify watch files which are create by NFS server into local machine(directory).

2) if not,is it possible to use any c++ library (unix) which can capture NFS delay.

I am sure this is very common thing but I could not figure out any solution.My application is also not server client application. it is simple jobs submission application which submit job and we got some outfile in current directory. ( code in c++

[inotify with NFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231243/inotify-with-nfs)

I got lot of info from tool which do file monitoring.But I want to  put effort if anybody has use tool with NFS delay. previous I tried (libev,inotify).

Comment: can you post a full example?

Comment: see http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html - You are missing fully compilable program. The problem might be because you used `IN_CREATE` for `inotify_add_watch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inotify tool never give predicable behavior with NFS .We can generally use in same file and folder but NFS you may not get desire behvior

Answer (score 0):

I found an SGI [FAM](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/) using an supervisor daemon to monitor file modification.  It supports NFS