# How to watch a remote file for any changes?

Tags: xml, linux, apache, http, push

My apologies if this has been answered before, But i can't find the correct answer anywhere.

I'm looking for something that would be the equivalent of Push Notifications (or at least my understanding of them)

> **Explanation**

I'm trying to set up a system where i can click a button & it'll essentially tell the client "This happened" (Simple explanation)

It wouldn't be a "check this saved file from * minutes ago, to see if there is any changes on remote file" As that could rack up high Bandwidth usage, I'm looking for a more If there's anything in the file, send the contents to the user.

Thank you for your time!

Further notes: The files would not be accessible locally, the most comparable thing is an rss reader.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4231277/85371 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81664

Answer (score 0):

you could use incrontab to monitor file/directory change, but it consume a lot of memory if you monitor huge directory.

So when incrontab found changes, you could do whatever you want, for example would be fire up an email to specific people. Hope it help.

(google incrontab)

Comment: I would only be monitoring a xml file on a remote server EG/ site.com/file.xml for changes.