# Alternatives to inotify for watching file changes in a NFS volume in a Docker container?

Tags: build, docker, watch, nfs, inotify

I'm attempting to setup my [build process](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/) in a docker container running on CoreOS over xhyve on OS X using corectl, which automatically mounts `/Users/[username]` via NFS.  I've discovered build tools such as [fsmonitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsmonitor) and [browser-sync](https://www.browsersync.io) rely on [`fs.watch`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) which uses [inotify on linux](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_availability) to watch for changes. inotify doesn't work over NFS [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194214) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4231277). [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090007/whats-the-right-way-to-setup-a-development-environment-on-os-x-with-docker) have addressed this issue and have decided to use rsync to send updated files into the container, which relies on a tool outside of the build container. I'd like to distribute a self-contained docker image that just works.

Is there an alternative to inotify that works over NFS?