# get notified about file change on NFS

Tags: file

I have to watch some file which a served by NFS. `inotify` does not give me events on files which live on a NFS share. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231243/inotify-with-nfs

Comment: I'm aware of the other question. That's why I explicitly asked for alternatives :/