# Python Watchdog PollingObserverVFS Performance enhancement

Tags: java, python, nfs, file-watcher, fileshare

I am running PollingObserverVFS on a directory that is on Dell ISILON Storage that has over 2 million files and it takes around 2 hours 30 min to detect changes. Is there a way to improve performance to detect changes faster like parallel processing or any other settings changes.

The code is pooling dell isilon storage to detect folder changes.

```
import datetime
import time 
import os
from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserverVFS
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


if __name__ == "__main__": 

 # Set format for displaying path 
my_event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()

path = "\\\\dd\\ARCHIVE\\"

print(path)
# Initialize logging event handler 
#event_handler = LoggingEventHandler() 
def on_any_event(event):

    print(datetime.datetime.now())

    if event.is_directory: 
        if event.event_type == 'created':
             print("Watchdog received directory create event - % s." % event.src_path) 

        elif event.event_type == 'modified': 
            # Event is modified, you can process it now 
            print("Watchdog received directory modified event - % s." % event.src_path) 

        elif event.event_type == 'moved': 
            # Event is modified, you can process it now 
           print("Watchdog received directory moved event - % s." % event.src_path) 
           print("Moved or Renamed directory path - % s." %event.dest_path )

        elif event.event_type == 'deleted': 
            # Event is modified, you can process it now 
           print("Watchdog received deleted event - % s." % event.src_path)


    elif event.event_type == 'created': 
            # Event is modified, you can process it now 
            print("Watchdog received file created event - % s." % event.src_path) 

    elif event.event_type == 'modified': 
            # Event is modified, you can process it now 
            print("Watchdog received modified file event - % s." % event.src_path) 

    elif event.event_type == 'moved': 
            # Event is modified, you can process it now 
           print("Watchdog received moved file event - % s." % event.src_path) 
           print("Moved or Renamed path - % s." %event.dest_path )

    elif event.event_type == 'deleted': 
            # Event is modified, you can process it now 
           print("Watchdog received deleted file event - % s." % event.src_path)        


my_event_handler.on_any_event = on_any_event

observer = PollingObserverVFS(stat=os.stat, listdir=os.listdir,polling_interval=60)
observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=True) 

# Start the observer 
observer.start() 
try: 
    while True: 
        # Set the thread sleep time 
        time.sleep(60) 
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    observer.stop() 
observer.join()
```

Comment: Did you try [inotify](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inotify with NFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231243/inotify-with-nfs)

Comment: we tried watchdog but its not consistent, it does not detect events all the time. inotify with NFS solution is an old solution or suggestion, i was looking if there are any new solution available

Comment: question is revised by the user to be more focused.

Comment: @Vaibav Did you find a new solution? I've found watchdog to be useful but now have reached the limit with hundreds of thousands of directories being monitored.