# Can EFS be used as an event source for triggering a Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I’ve successfully created a Lambda function that can be triggered by an S3 file upload to a certain bucket and then downloads that file to EFS. I was wondering if the opposite workflow is possible, such that, a file uploaded to a given EFS directory would trigger Lambda to upload that file to S3?

For instance, in the `serverless.yml` or CloudFormation template I use to deploy the former workflow, the trigger event is defined as `s3:ObjectCreated:*`, but is there an equivalent for EFS?

If not, what is a good alternative solution for this workflow, setting up a trigger via CloudWatch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not an equivalent of S3 trigger for EFS. [Inotify will not work with EFS either.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231243/inotify-with-nfs)

You could set up an EventBridge scheduled event that triggers a lambda to scan an EFS folder periodically, but it can become costly.

Comment: I see, so this can only be set up using a schedule-based rule rather than a pattern-based rule for EventBrige?

Comment: Yeah, EventBridge or CloudWatch scheduled events are basically cron jobs.