# Can VS Code watch changes to files mounted via NFS in WSL?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nfs, filesystemwatcher

One very helpful feature of VS Code and its extensions is the ability to watch files and folders and react if they change. In the VS Code API, this is implemented by [FileSystemWatcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemWatcher).

If I mount an NFS volume in a WSL distribution and open VS Code for a folder within that volume with the Remote - WSL extension, will VS Code be able to watch files and folders?

*After some more searching*: I'd love to be told differently, but according to [this blog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/File-Watcher-Issues), file watching is implemented with inotify on Linux. And inotify probably still does work through NFS, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231243/inotify-with-nfs) some time ago.